# Binary Tree Testing?

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

I have a BinaryTree class, a TreeNode class and a BinaryTestClass that creates a BinaryTree where values can be inserted as a root into the TreeNode. However when I run the program on the test class it doesn't show everything that should be shown.

BinaryTree Class:

```
public class BinaryTree <T extends Comparable<T>> implements BTree<T>{


TreeNode<T> root;

public BinaryTree(){
    root = null;
}


public BTree<T> left() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return left();
}

public BTree<T> right() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return right();
}

public void insert(T value) {
    if (root == null){
        root = new TreeNode(value);
    }else if (value.compareTo(value()) < 0){
        root.left().insert(value);
    } else{
        root.right().insert(value);
    }

}

public T value() {
    return value();
  }

}
```

TreeNode class:

```
public class TreeNode<T extends Comparable<T>>{

 T value;
 BinaryTree<T> left, right;


public TreeNode(T value) {
    this.value = value;
    left = new BinaryTree<T>();
    right = new BinaryTree<T>();
}


public T value() {
  return value;
}

public BinaryTree<T> left() {
    return left;
}

public BinaryTree<T> right() {
    return right;
  }

 }
```

In this test class I have the method that instantiates an empty BinaryTree object. However when I run the test method, it only appears with the "Inserting the Values: " part of the code.

```
public class BinaryTreeTest {

/**
 * @throws java.lang.Exception
 */
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
}

/**
 * @throws java.lang.Exception
 */
@AfterClass
public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
}

/**
 * @throws java.lang.Exception
 */
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
}

/**
 * @throws java.lang.Exception
 */
@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
}

@Test
public void test() {
       BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree(); // empty tree
          int intVal;
          // insert 10 random ints
          System.out.print("Inserting the values: ");
          for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
             intVal = (int) (Math.random()*100);
             System.out.print(intVal + " ");
             tree.insert(intVal);
          }
          System.out.println(tree);
      } 
  }
```

What do I do so that it shows with the full list of values that are put in the tree?

Answer (score 0):

Simply doing `System.out.println(tree)` will not print out the values in your tree. You need to create a method such as `printTree()` in your `BinaryTree` class that will travel through your tree and print the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just say System.out.println(tree), You have to write a custom method. I have drafted a basic method which you can refer. This may not be entirely correct.

```
public static void printTree(Treenode root)
{
if(root == null)
return;
else
    {
        System.out.println(root.value);
        printTree(root.left());
        printTree(root.right());
     }
}
```

This is for preorder. You can write either postorder or inorder

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print your class you must Override toString() method of Object.